How can I put a web with a login inside an iframe of another domain?
I'm trying to embed a page inside another. Both belong to different domains. I need to show a login page inside the iframe, and when a user logs show them the musical streaming service they signed up for. I need it inside the iframe because it's a service for another client, who has their own customers that sign up in there.
First of all, I set the headers so scripts are allowed to run inside the iframe, on both sites.
header('Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-modals allow-forms');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site');
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 'true');

This still doesn't work, because it doesn't let me store the info I need (username) inside either $_SESSION or $_COOKIE, the one that works for that purpose. I'm stuck at what I should be doing now. I looked at multiple questions about similar things but I can't figure out what to do.

session.cookie_samesite can't have a "None" value, only "Lax" and "Strict", or, if needed, an empty value.

This currently lacks way too much detail, for us to be able to say anything specific. We don't know how these two sites are supposed to communicate, or where you tried to use/set a session or cookies. But in general: Having users login via an iframe, is not a good idea to begin with. Users should be able to verify via the browser address bar, which site they will be sending their login credentials to - which won't be possible, if you embed the login page via an iframe. [...]

[...] And while you might not have malicious intentions here, this is dangerous nevertheless - because you would be teaching users, that providing their login credentials in such a scenario was okay in general - which could make them vulnerable to phishing attacks, on the next site that uses a similar mechanism.

The session is set when the user tries to log in, once it verifies it's the correct user and password, it sets the session to that username so the page inside the Iframe can use it. I get it's dangerous, I'll explore other options that are safer since our client wanted to be able to provide our service without their customers seeing the original url
